# Inner Product of two 4-vectors

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, notation

I have a question on the inner product of two 4-vectors. As per the definition the inner product of two 4-vectors is defined as,

$$\vec A.\vec B = -A^0B^0+A^1B^1+A^2B^2+A^3B^3$$

From linear algebra, the above must be true because a vector space must be closed. The confusion starts when I write the individual vectors in their component form viz,

$\vec A = (-A^0, A^1, A^2, A^3)$ and $\vec B = (-B^0, B^1, B^2, B^3)$

If I now multiply the vectors component wise shouldn't the time component be, $-A^0.-B^0 = A^0B^0$? What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you define $A$ and $B$ like this? Have you checked e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Standard_basis,_(%E2%88%92+++)_signature)?

Comment: Do you know tensor contraction?

Comment: $\mathbf A=\left(A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3\right),\:\:\mathbf B=\left(B^0,B^1,B^2,B^3\right)$.

Comment: "From linear algebra, the above must be true because a vector space must be closed". What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set up an invariant scalar product of 4-vectors in Minkowski space one needs covariant and contravariant components.
Both are connected by the metric tensor $\eta_{ik} =diag(-1,+1,+1,+1)$ (Here the east-coast convention is used).

So if $\vec{A}= (A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3)$ and $\vec{B}=(B^0,B^1,B^2,B^3)$

The Lorentz-invariant scalar product of both is using Einstein's summation comvention (summation of the same indices, but one up (contravariant), the other one down (covariant)):

$$A^i B_i \equiv \sum_{i=0,\ldots,3}  A^i B_i  \equiv  \sum_{i,k=0,\ldots,3}  A^i B^k \eta_{ik}  = -A^0 B^0 + A^1 B^1 +A^2 B^2  + A^3 B^3$$

The relationship between the covariant and contravariant components is :

$$ B_i = B^k \eta_{ik} \equiv  \sum_{k=0,\ldots,3} B^k \eta_{ik}  $$

As the metric tensor $\eta_{ik}$ is symmetric in the indices it does not matter if the contraction of indices is done with the first or the second index. Here it is done with the second index.

Only an expression with completely contracted indices (same type and number of indices up and also down) is Lorentz-invariant. Only such an expression would deserve the name scalar product and transforms as a scalar under  Lorentz-transformations.